# Private Polygon Chain

Tags: private-blockchain, polygon, blockchain-fork

As we have an option to create a private Ethereum chain and a private chain using GoQuorum do we have an option to create a private chain using Polygon and do the transactions among those nodes of the private chain alone?

Your inputs are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at Kaleido for your Private Polygon Edge implementation. All the nodes in your private network remain private and nothing is submitted to a public node. Here's a quote from the docs ...

**Polygon on Kaleido**

Polygon is an Ethereum scaling solution that aims to increase transaction speed and reduce transaction cost on Ethereum.

Polygon Edge extends the success that Polygon has had connecting with mainnet Ethereum and now makes it possible for anyone to create their own private polygon blockchain network while maintaining full compatibility with Ethereum smart contracts and transaction.

Here is a link to their documentation: -

https://docs.kaleido.io/kaleido-platform/protocol/polygon/